# Transforming a game to an object-oriented version

Tags: python, class, oop, object, python-3.x

I have programmed a simple console game that allows me to move my player inside a small level with walls and blank spaces. It's all done using only few simple functions.

I'm rather new to Python but I'd like to learn OOP next, how would I continue from here on if I wanted to make this game object-oriented?

I understand classes and objects *quite* well, but bear with me if I don't understand all the answers.

Here's the current game:

```
LEVEL = [
    'xxxxxx',
    'x    x',
    'x i  x',
    'x    x',
    'x    x',
    'xxxxxx'
]


def get_block(x, y):
    """Gets a block at the given coordinates."""
    try:
        return LEVEL[y][x]
    except IndexError:
        return None


def set_block(x, y, block):
    """Sets a block at the given coordinates."""
    try:
        LEVEL[y] = LEVEL[y][:x] + block + LEVEL[y][x + 1:]
    except IndexError:
        pass


def get_player_position():
    """Gets player's position."""
    for y, row in enumerate(LEVEL):
        for x, column in enumerate(row):
            if column == 'i':
                return x, y


def set_player_position(x, y):
    """Sets player's position."""
    block = get_block(x, y)
    if block == ' ':
        px, py = get_player_position()
        set_block(px, py, ' ')
        set_block(x, y, 'i')


def main():
    """Entry point for the program."""
    cmd = ''
    while cmd.lower() not in ('quit', 'q'):
        print('\n' * 30)
        for row in LEVEL:
            print(row)
        cmd = input('Command: ').lower()
        px, py = get_player_position()
        if cmd == 'w':
            set_player_position(px, py - 1)
        elif cmd == 's':
            set_player_position(px, py + 1)
        elif cmd == 'a':
            set_player_position(px - 1, py)
        elif cmd == 'd':
            set_player_position(px + 1, py)
    print('Bye.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to to? If you have a precise programming question then fine but a vague question asking how do I change my code to do something different is, I believe, off topic here.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I'm trying to practice OOP, which I'm extremely new to. I was hoping to get some help with transforming this code to use classes (such as `Player` class or `Level` class maybe?). I understand if it's the wrong place to ask, can you recommend any "right" place to ask?

Comment: See the help pages linked from the top of every Stackoverflow page for details of what is on topic here. I do not know Python, but there are probably many tutorials and help forums elsewhere on the web. When you have clear questions then please return here and I am sure the Python community will be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question is pretty open-ended, so it's difficult to give an all-encompassing answer — so what I've done instead is identified one data-structure in your existing code and turned it an class.

Functions which used to operate on global data-datastructure, are now all public methods of instances of the class which is the only ones that's allowed make changes to the data held inside it in a private attribute named `_field`.

Doing  this sort of thing is an essential first step in writing object-oriented software.

Hope you find the example somewhat enlightening.

```
class PlayingField(object):
    # Class constants
    PLAYER = 'i'
    EMPTY = ' '
    EDGE = 'x'
    DEFAULT_SIZE = 6

    def __init__(self, size=DEFAULT_SIZE):
        X, EMPTY = self.EDGE, self.EMPTY
        self._size = size
        # build playing field
        self._field = [size*X] + (size-2)*[X + (size-2)*EMPTY + X] + [size*X]
        self._set_block(2, 2, self.PLAYER)  # Initialize player's position.

    def display(self):
        print(30*'\n')
        for row in self._field:
            print(row)

    def get_player_position(self):
        """Gets player's position."""
        for y, row in enumerate(self._field):
            for x, column in enumerate(row):
                if column == self.PLAYER:
                    return x, y
        else:
            raise ValueError("Couldn't determine player's location on field")

    def set_player_position(self, x, y):
        """Sets player's position."""
        block = self._get_block(x, y)
        if block == self.EMPTY:
            px, py = self.get_player_position()
            self._set_block(px, py, self.EMPTY)
            self._set_block(x, y, self.PLAYER)


    # Private methods
    def _get_block(self, x, y):
        """Gets a block at the given coordinates."""
        try:
            return self._field[y][x]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def _set_block(self, x, y, block):
        """Sets a block at the given coordinates."""
        try:
            self._field[y] = self._field[y][:x] + block + self._field[y][x + 1:]
        except IndexError:
            pass

def main():
    """Entry point for the program."""
    field = PlayingField()
    cmd = ''
    while cmd.lower() not in ('quit', 'q'):
        field.display()
        cmd = input('Command: ').lower()
        px, py = field.get_player_position()
        if cmd == 'w':
            field.set_player_position(px, py - 1)
        elif cmd == 's':
            field.set_player_position(px, py + 1)
        elif cmd == 'a':
            field.set_player_position(px - 1, py)
        elif cmd == 'd':
            field.set_player_position(px + 1, py)
    print('Bye.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I need more help, but I'm going to ask a different question for that.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any questions about what's in my answer — which I just updated a little — feel free to do so here in the comments. One unrelated suggestion I have for you is to make the `_field` attribute a list of `bytearray` objects instead of strings because the former are mutable, so changing their contents would be easier.